# Sort Map by the keys

Tags: javascript, dictionary, google-apps-script

How can I easily sort the map by the keys in Google Apps Script? Somewhere I found the code `new Map([...map.keys()].sort()`. According the log it does the comparison but it finishes with the "TypeError: Iterator value 3 is not an entry object". Here is the snippet:

```
function mapSortTest() {
  
var map = new Map();

map.set(2, 'two');
map.set(3, 'three');
map.set(1, 'one');

for (let key of map.keys()) Logger.log(key + " (" + typeof(key) + "): " + map.get(key));

var sortedMap = new Map([...map.keys()].sort((a,b) => {Logger.log("a: " + a + ", b: " + b); a-b;}));
  
for (let key of sortedMap.keys()) Logger.log(key + " (" + typeof(key) + "): " + sortedMap.get(key));
  
/* here I expect:
1 (number): one
2 (number): two
3 (number): three
*/

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Tree Map instead of Map if you want to get the sorted keys.

Answer (score 0):

### It should be `new Map([...map.entries()]` and not `new Map([...map.keys()]`

The following will work as intended:

```js
function mapSortTest() {
  
  var map = new Map();
  
  map.set(3, 'three');
  map.set(2, 'two');
  map.set(1, 'one');
  
  for (let key of map.keys()) Logger.log(key + " (" + typeof(key) + "): " + map.get(key));
  
  var sortedMap = new Map([...map.entries()].sort());
  
  for (let key of sortedMap.keys()) Logger.log(key + " (" + typeof(key) + "): " + sortedMap.get(key));
  
  /* here I expect:
  1 (number): one
  2 (number): two
  3 (number): three
  */
}
```

Explanation:

`map.keys()` will return you only the keys, not the values, see:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/keys
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/entries

Comment: I tried your code. It doesn't finish with the TypeError but it also doesn't change the order of items in the sortedMap no matter I use a-b or b-a in inside the sort (a-b should be in original post, sorry).

Comment: I see. What about just `var sortedMap = new Map([...map.entries()].sort());  
  for (let key of sortedMap.keys()) Logger.log(key + " (" + typeof(key) + "): " + sortedMap.get(key));`?

Comment: This works for the easy snippet above, but there is more complex sorting in original code so I need some (not necessary) anonymous comparison function inside the sort(...). I experimented a lot but nothing changes the order, only your's "emtpy" sort().

Comment: I will look into your sort() function -but the point is: you need to access map.entries() instead of maps.keys()

Comment: `sort((a,b) => a[0]-b[0])` and with the log: `sort((a,b) => {Logger.log(...);return a[0]-b[0]})`, **return** is important here. Generally thank you for showing me right direction.

Comment: I believe `var sortedMap = new Map([...map.entries()].sort((a,b)=>{Logger.log("a: " + a + ", b: " + b); return a[0]-b[0]})); ` should sort and return your values correctly?!